# Using the w2ui combo field, how to trigger remote URL search on every key press?

Tags: search, triggers, w2ui

I'm using the w2ui combo field and set the URL property to search results from a backend database. This is all good and working.

But - the backend search is not triggered for every key press - it only seems to be triggered upon first key(s) entered, and subsequently if I backspace everything and re-type a new search. I want the backend search to be triggered upon each key press.

The issue I'm having is the following:

1. User inputs the number 2, db returns hundreds of matches. For example, the first 10 might be:
   20001
   20002
   20003
   20004
   20005
   20006
   20007
   20008
   20009
   20010
2. If the user next inputs the number "1", it says no Matches, because no remote call to the database occurred. It seems w2ui is searching the first list returned, for anything beginning with "21", and clearly the list above has no matches beginning with 21.
3. If I use backspace to remove the "21" that was typed, and immediately/quickly type "21", then a call is made to the database and it'll correctly return values beginning with 21.

Question: I want to trigger the backend search on "any" keypress. This means if they press 2, backend returns all results beginning with 2 (correct - this happens today), but if they then press a key like the number 1 - I want backend to be searched again, Instead of the existing list to be cached and searched as its doing today.

Any thoughts/ideas on how to accomplish this?

Many Thanks

I tried searching the w2ui documentation, unable to find a way to achieve this.